# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException upon LinkedHashSet iteration

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

Please, help me understand the error I am getting:

```
private void replayHistory() {
    synchronized (alarmsHistory) {
        for (AlarmEvent alarmEvent : alarmsHistory) {
            LOG.error("replayHistory " + alarmEvent.type + " " + alarmEvent.source);
            sendNotification(alarmEvent.type, alarmEvent.source, alarmEvent.description, 
                    alarmEvent.clearOnOtherStations, alarmEvent.forceClearOnOtherStations);         
        }
    }
}
```

and the method that adds an element to it

```
private void addToAlarmsHistory(AlarmEvent alarmEvent) {
    synchronized (alarmsHistory) {
        LOG.error("addToAlarmsHistory " + alarmEvent.type + " " + alarmEvent.source);
        alarmsHistory.add(alarmEvent);
    }
}
```

both methods and the Set

`private volatile Set<AlarmEvent> alarmsHistory = new LinkedHashSet<AlarmEvent>();`

are defined in

`JmxGwReloadThread extends Thread class`

which is an inner class in

`AlarmManager class`

that has a method

```
private void addToReplayHistory(AlarmEvent alarmEvent) {
    if ((jmxThread != null) && (jmxThread.isAlive())) {
        jmxThread.addToAlarmsHistory(alarmEvent);
    }
}
```

which is being called by different interfaces (cannot assure when and how often)

At some point JmxThread is started and calls replayHistory method

`java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown, the root is from the

```
for (AlarmEvent alarmEvent : alarmsHistory) {
```

The code propably tries to add an element to the alarmsHistory and when interator

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(LinkedHashMap.java:390)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$KeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:401)
    at AlarmManager$JmxGwReloadThread.replayHistory(AlarmManager.java:568)
    at AlarmManager$JmxGwReloadThread.run(AlarmManager.java:532)
```

throws exception upon calling nextEntry, but should't synchronization prevent from such an issue?

Logs show that synchronization does not work - replayHistory should iterate over all its elements (I can asure its more then one single HEARTBEAT_INFO FM) but it's interrupted by the addToReplayHistory call.

```
2013-07-11 11:58:33,951 Thread-280 ERROR AlarmManager$JmxGwReloadThread.replayHistory(AlarmManager.java:570)  - replayHistory HEARTBEAT_INFO FM
2013-07-11 11:58:33,951 Thread-280 ERROR AlarmManager$JmxGwReloadThread.addToAlarmsHistory(AlarmManager.java:550)  -  addToAlarmsHistory HEARTBEAT_INFO FM
2013-07-11 11:58:33,952 Thread-280 ERROR Log4jConfigurator$UncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(Log4jConfigurator.java:253)  - Detected uncaught exception in thread: Thread-280
```

Comment: Can you please make your code [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? Especially show us a complete class that shows this behaviour. Because your current posted code should work so far.

Comment: How can you iterate directly over a LinkedHashMap? alarmsHistory cannot be a LinkedHashMap as "for (AlarmEvent alarmEvent : alarmsHistory) { .. }" would not compile. Your example makes no sense to me. Please post the full example as the comment before proposes.

Comment: Edited my initial post, sorry for incomplete and misleading data.

Comment: The code uses a `LinkedHashSet`, but the stack trace mentions a `LinkedHashMap`?

Comment: Also I think the first call to `LOG` should be in the loop, not before it.

Comment: Yes, it's in the lopp, I had some problems with identation and copy-pasted it in the wrong line.

Comment: @mmirwaldt I am not iterating over LinkedHashMap, LinkedHashSet extends HashSet. Hashset has public Iterator<E> iterator() { return map.keySet().iterator(); } which retrieves iterator from map implementation this is why it's in the stack trace.

Answer (score 4):

One thing OP (and probably most people) should be aware of:

**ConcurrentModificationException has nothing to do with multi-threading.**

Although multi-threading makes it much easier to happen, but the core of this problem has nothing to do with multi-threading.

This is mostly caused by scenario like,

1. Get the iterator from a collection,
2. Before finish using that iterator, the collection is structurally modified.
3. Keep on using the iterator after 2.  The iterator will detect the collection is structurally modified and will throw out ConcurrentModificationException.

Of course, not all collection have such behavior, e.g. ConcurrentHashMap.  Definition of "Structurally Modified" is different for different collection too.

That means, even I have only 1 thread, if I do something like:

```
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    //....
    for (String s: strings) {  // iterating through the collection
        strings.add("x");   // structurally modifying the collection
    }
```

I will get ConcurrentModificationException even it is all happening in single thread.

There are different ways to solve the problem, depending on your requirement or problem. e.g.

1. If it is simply due to multi-thread access, proper synchronize access can be one solution
2. You may make use of Collection that iterator is safe from structural modification (e.g. ConcurrentHashMap)
3. Adjust your logic to either re-acquire the iterator again if you modified the collection, or makes your modification using the iterator (some collection impls allows that), or make sure modification to collection happens after you finish using the iterator.

Given that your code seems having proper synchronization on `alarmHistory`, there are two directions you would want to check

1. Is there any possible modification of `alarmHistory` inside `sendNotification()`?  For example, adding or removing from `alarmHistory`?
2. Is there other possible unsynchronized access to alarmHistory which may modify the structure?

Answer (score 2):

If one thread iterates, and another thread adds, you're hosed.

Given that your code *seems* to synchronise access to the two relevant blocks of code, look for *other* unsynchronized code that adds/removes from alarmsHistory.

Comment: If the lock is held by the thread which iterates, how is it possible for another thread to add??

Comment: But if the two Threads have their own instances, why is there a `ConcurrentModificationException`?

Comment: @Dahaka I just realised that the lock object is the collection. Further edits :/

Answer (score 1):

The only idea which comes to my head that you have an intricate logic behind the scene. I think the `sendNotification` somehow recursively invokes `addToReplayHistory`. So, the multithreading is a red herring, the log file shows only one thread involved, and immideately after sendNotification there is addToReplayHistory call which modifies the collection and breaks the interator.

More info is in the javadoc for the exception:

> Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has
>   been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread
>   issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of
>   an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, if a
>   thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the
>   collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this
>   exception.

Answer (score 0):

To add some details to [kan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17591415/621519):

The `synchronized` block in Java is [reentrant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html):

> ### Reentrant Synchronization
>
> Recall that a thread cannot acquire a lock owned by another thread. But a thread can acquire a lock that it already owns. Allowing a thread to acquire the same lock more than once enables reentrant synchronization. This describes a situation where synchronized code, directly or indirectly, invokes a method that also contains synchronized code, and both sets of code use the same lock. Without reentrant synchronization, synchronized code would have to take many additional precautions to avoid having a thread cause itself to block.

So like kan pointed out, it might in fact be that not multiple threads are modifying your collection but only one thread which, due to the reentrant behavior, may always acquire the lock.

The things you should look for to fix the exception are recursive calls between synchronized blocks, or unsychronized access to `alarmsHistory`.

You can also look into concurrent collections like [ConcurrentSkipList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) or [CopyOnWriteArraySet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.html). Both should prevent the exception, but beware of their behavior and performance characteristics described in the JavaDoc.